# Synchronizing two MDC drawers

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-components, material-components-web

In my page I have two Material Design Component drawers with the same items. One is permanent for desktop/tablet display, the other is hidden/modal for mobile display.

```
<aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--permanent">
    <div class="mdc-drawer__header">
        <h3 class="mdc-drawer__title">App</h3>
        <h6 class="mdc-drawer__subtitle">@username</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
        <nav class="mdc-list--permanent">@menu_drawer_content</nav>
    </div>
</aside>

<aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--modal">
    <div class="mdc-drawer__header">
        <h3 class="mdc-drawer__title">App</h3>
        <h6 class="mdc-drawer__subtitle">@username</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
        <nav class="mdc-list">@menu_drawer_content</nav>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Both are initialised:

```
modalDrawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer--modal'));
let list = mdc.list.MDCList.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-list--permanent'));
list.wrapFocus = true;
```

I have javascript that toggles one over the other:

```
let smallForm = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches;

function resized() {
    let smallForm_ = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches;
    if (smallForm !== smallForm_) {
        smallForm = smallForm_;
        changedMedia();
    }
}

function changedMedia() {
    let drawerButton = $('.mdc-top-app-bar__row > section > button');
    if (smallForm) {
        $('.mdc-drawer--permanent').hide();
        drawerButton.show();
    } else {
        $('.mdc-drawer--permanent').show();
        drawerButton.hide();
        modalDrawer.open = false;
    }
}
```

A bug that remains is that selecting an item on one drawer does not select the same item on the other drawer. If I transition from one size to another the selected item will not match the content.

Can I link the two drawers such that selection on one will change the state of the other (especially without triggering events on the "other" drawer or entering a recursive loop cross-notifying loop)?

Edit: Added bounty. [Full source](https://github.com/luxe-app/luxe/blob/a49f9fb00f570a3393bdc123fa2da815780183f8/public/javascripts/main.js).

Comment: You probably already tried this, but does MDC not play nice if you just toggle the `mdc-drawer--permanent` and `mdc-list--permanent` classes (and component instantiation) on a single drawer element with your `matchMedia` js (so that you don't have to synchronize the list element selection at all)?

Comment: It doesn't work because of the behind-the-scenes stuff that happens in the initialisation block. I just gave it a try anyway, and it was confused about whether it should be modal or permanent, doing the wrong thing in both wide and narrow forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out how to "undo" the MDC component instantiation so you can use a single drawer and just switch between modal and permanent while preserving the selection of the drawer list item. The important part of the snippet below is to call `destroy()` when switching media so that you can modify the drawer class and re-instantiate successfully.

```js
let timeout;
let activeBar;
let activeDrawer;
let activeList;
const actualResizeHandler = () => {
  const fixedStyles = () => {
    document.body.style = 'display: flex; height: 100vh;';
    document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer-app-content').style = 'flex: auto; overflow: auto;';
    document.querySelector('.main-content').style = 'height: 100%; overflow: auto;';
    document.querySelector('.mdc-top-app-bar').style = 'position: absolute;';
  };

  const modalStyles = () => {
    document.body.removeAttribute('style');
    document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer-app-content').removeAttribute('style');
    document.querySelector('.main-content').removeAttribute('style');
    document.querySelector('.mdc-top-app-bar').removeAttribute('style');
  };
  
  const bar = document.querySelector('.mdc-top-app-bar');
  const drawer = document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer');
  const list = document.querySelector('.mdc-list');
  if (typeof activeBar !== 'undefined') {
    activeBar.destroy();
  }
    
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    if (typeof activeList !== 'undefined') {
      activeList.destroy();
    }
    
    drawer.classList.add('mdc-drawer--modal');
    drawer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="mdc-drawer-scrim"></div>');
    modalStyles();
    activeBar = mdc.topAppBar.MDCTopAppBar.attachTo(bar);
    activeBar.listen('MDCTopAppBar:nav', () => {
      if (typeof activeDrawer !== 'undefined') {
        activeDrawer.open = !activeDrawer.open;
      }
      
    });
    
    activeDrawer = mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(drawer);
  } else {
    const scrim = document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer-scrim');
    if (scrim) {
      scrim.remove();
    }
    
    if (typeof activeDrawer !== 'undefined') {
      activeDrawer.destroy();
    }
    
    drawer.classList.remove('mdc-drawer--modal');
    fixedStyles();
    activeList = mdc.list.MDCList.attachTo(list);
    activeList.wrapFocus = true;
  }
};

const resizeThrottler = () => {
  if (!timeout) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null;
      actualResizeHandler();
     }, 66);
  }
};
  
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeThrottler, false);
actualResizeHandler();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Material Modal / Dismissible Drawer Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <aside class="mdc-drawer">
      <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
        <nav class="mdc-list">
          <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" tabindex="0" aria-current="page">
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Item 1</span>
          </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Item 2</span>
          </a>
          <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Item 3</span>
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="mdc-drawer-app-content">
      <header class="mdc-top-app-bar">
        <div class="mdc-top-app-bar__row">
          <section class="mdc-top-app-bar__section mdc-top-app-bar__section--align-start">
            <button class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon mdc-icon-button">menu</button>
            <span class="mdc-top-app-bar__title">Title</span>
          </section>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main class="main-content">
        <div class="mdc-top-app-bar--fixed-adjust">
          App Content
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```